# jQuery CSS - Autocomplete Dropdown over Modal Box

Tags: jquery, css

So I am working on an Autocomplete text input made with jQuery. Unfortunately, this input is inside a Modal Box and I am trying to have the drop down go over the modal box instead of using the scrollbar but with no success.

[image: Autocontrol example]

My CSS:

```
`.ui-autocomplete { 
position: absolute;
 cursor: default;
 background:white }   


`html .ui-autocomplete { width:1px; } 
.ui-menu {
    list-style:none;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0;
    display:block;
    float: left;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu {
    margin-top: -3px;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    zoom: 1;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding:.2em .4em;
    line-height:1.5;
    zoom:1;
    z-index:1;   
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-hover,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-active {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: -1px;
}`
```

Comment: unfortunately the overflow of the modal is handled by the scrolling and therefore if the dropdown goes  below, it is classed as part of the modal overflow and therefore will also be handled by the modals scrollbar - that's why you should try not to put things like that in modals, bad ux

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Pete, unfortunately I'm adding extra functionality on an existing app so I can't really get around changing the design.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an iframe you wouldn't be able to do this. If it's modal content on the same page your best option would be to review the overflow and size properties of the modal content.